# OBR START command not found?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, obr

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-osgi-bundle-repository.html

However when I try to use the OBR START command I get this:

[image]

As you can see, my HELP command list also states that there is no obr:start command installed.
I'm using felix framework 4.4.0 that I just downloaded from the website.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, someone tell me I'm not alone in the universe. :'(

Comment: You're not alone in the universe. Just the only one using OBR. That documentation seems to be severely out of date.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Hey Neil, could you please elaborate on this? Is `OBR` somehow out of favor? Should it be avoided? PS I am aware of high-level tools like `Karaf` that provide various options for deployment like from `Maven` repo.

Answer (score 0):

At some point the `obr:start` command was moved to the `felix` namespace. You can type `felix:start` or simply `start`.

Unfortunately, a lot of `Felix` documentation is out of date.